# why is the last file in my loop not correctly copying?

Tags: c

For the cs50 course, I have to 'recover' jpeg images from a deleted memory card. I currently have each of the images up to the last one working, but the last one won't work. I know this because the command "check50 cs50/problems/2024/x/recover" was supplied to me. This command checks the correctness of my code. As far as I can tell there are no visual errors in my code though.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cs50.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Syntax: ./recovery 'file name'");
        return 1;
    }
    char *input = argv[1];
    FILE *f = fopen(input, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *jpeg;
    char filename[8];
    int filenum = 0;
    int jpgcount = 0;
    bool size = true;
    for (int i = 0; true; i++)
        {
            BYTE *JPEGS = malloc(512 * sizeof(BYTE));
            int AreYouFalse = fread(JPEGS, 512, 1, f);
            if ((int)JPEGS[0] == 0xff && (int)JPEGS[1] == 0xd8 && (int)JPEGS[2] == 0xff && ((int)JPEGS[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                if (jpgcount == 0)
                {
                    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", filenum);
                    jpeg = fopen(filename, "w");
                    fwrite(JPEGS, 512, 1, jpeg);
                }
                else
                {
                    filenum++;
                    fclose(jpeg);
                    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", filenum);
                    jpeg = fopen(filename, "w");
                    fwrite(JPEGS, 512, 1, jpeg);
                }
                jpgcount++;
            }
            else if (jpgcount > 0)
            {
                fwrite(JPEGS, 512, 1, jpeg);
            }
            if (AreYouFalse == 0)
            {
                free(JPEGS);
                fclose(jpeg);
                fclose(f);
                break;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

[image: This is the outputted last image]

Link to my visual studio code https://bug-free-doodle-4jjx9gwrp9wx27gvv.github.dev/?autoStart=true&folder=%2Fworkspaces%2F158769934&vscodeChannel=stable
(use the command " check50 cs50/problems/2024/x/recover" to check the error messages"

I have tried to ask AI to help me but it couldn't figure out the problem either.

Comment: You should check `AreYouFalse` __before__ working with that data

Comment: Instead of ```for (int i = 0; true; i++)``` have something like ```while(AreYouFalse)```

Comment: `printf("Could not open file.\n");`  is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Tell the user the name that was used in attempting to open the file, and give them the reason the file could not be opened.  Also, print the message to stderr.  Indeed, print all error messages to stderr.  This is a common use case, and there is a convenient function you can use.  Use `perror(input);` instead of `printf`

Comment: The idiomatic way to structure the loop will almost certainly fix the issue for you: `while (fread(...) == 1) { ... }`